# Battery backup for Workstation & Printer

Tags: printing, ups, electrical-power, battery

I have been tasked with finding a price for a battery backup solution for our printers. 
Each printer is listed at 240v 24a <5.5kW and each workstation is using a 500w power supply.

We are probably going to add more batteries to our existing UPS to provide power for all our printers, but we would like to price our individual UPS's just incase.

Does anyone have any recommendations for an adequate UPS that can be used free-standing, as there's no racks near the printers.

Comment: Seriously, 240v 24A. What make/model? If that current rating is correct then this is a very high power requirement and will need specialist kit - more like a generator than a UPS.

Comment: Why do you need battery backup to your printers?  Is it to keep them up during a power outage so that your users can continue to print, or to absorb power glitches?  It's an odd requirement either way and one that I've not heard of anybody needing before today.

Comment: I couldn't find any documents, but I'm pretty sure having a printer on a battery is doable, but it will really kill your battery much quicker than you would want. For the larger UPSes pretty sure I've had APC say that they don't recommend that.

Comment: I believe 24A is a typo and it should rather be 2.4A. European in-house power cabling is typically rated for up to 16A, a simple power cord with an IEC 320 C3 plug has a maximum rating of 10A.

Comment: 24A may not be a typo as 240v@24A is around 5.7KW. Maybe the OP works for a reprographics/design shop with some big kit.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the printers in question are Ricoh C-900, and the numbers are correct. We are in florida, and suffer many lightning storms that interrupt power for a couple seconds at a time and we cannot let these interrupt our production process. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on how long you wanted to run the devices. Each workstation/printer pair could be connected to just about any 240v 8kAH UPS (they run about $10k) and it would keep those going for 10 to 30 minutes (much more when not printing). You could add extension batteries to double that time (or more); each extension is going to cost though.

Answer (score 0):

We use the APC BACK-UPS series - both 550 and 700 rated versions.  These are mainly to allow for small power glitches i.e. "brownouts" so the PCs keep going or to give us a few minutes to shutdown in the event of a "proper" power cut.  They don't give much run-time.

Note that just because a workstation has a 500W power supply, it won't need as much as that in terms of UPS power - your best bet is to buy a small monitor that you plug into the power supply then plug your equipment into and it tells you how much power you are drawing and the load factor (generally > 90% for most IT equipment so not a worry) so you can then work out the UPS you need for the run time you want